# PFQuery Limit Query

Tags: parse-platform

I have a user , activty, photo class. Where user likes other users Attached screenshot of Activity Class https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33860877/Activity.png

My problem is that when a user likes more than 1000, the limitation on the "filter likes" query will cause below method to get users that the user has already liked because number of activity (likes) more than 1000. What should be done here to avoid this?

```
-(void) loaddata {

PFQuery *filterUsers = [PFUser query];
[filterUsers whereKey:kMUParseUserAccountStatus equalTo:@"Active"];
filterUsers.limit =1000;


PFQuery *filterLikes = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:kMUActivityClassKey];
[filterLikes whereKey:kMUActivityUserFromKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
filterLikes.limit =1000;


PFQuery *query = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:kMUPhotoClassKey];
[query whereKey:kMUPhotoUserKey notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query whereKey:kMUPhotoPicturePriorityKey equalTo:@(0)];
[query whereKey:kMUPhotoUserKey matchesQuery:filterUsers];
[query whereKey:kMUPhotoUserKey doesNotMatchKey:kMUActivityUserToKey inQuery:filterLikes];
[query includeKey:kMUPhotoUserKey];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if(!error)
    {

        if(objects.count>0)
        {


            [self updateInformation];

        }


        else
        {
            if(objects.count==0)
            {
                self.hasMorePhotos = false;
            }

        }
    }


}];
}
```

Comment: have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to work around the 1000 record limit.

If I understand you correctly, you want to show photos that the current user HAS NOT YET LIKED. Your solution is not efficient, as you compare a key in a query of 1000 objects (or, if the limit was not 1000, your solution would perhaps need to compare thousands of objects).

If you need to filter out liked photos, you could instead store an array of objectIDs on the user. When the user likes a photo, you could add this objectId to an array on the User object, or another object tied to the user. Then, in your query, you could compare with this array rather than another query:

```
[query whereKey:@"objectId" notContainedIn:arrayOfLikedObjectIds];
```

Comment: how is this solution efficient though? suppose we're talking about instagram. Each user has 1000s of likes, and you're proposing to store them in an array? then you'd need to either sort this array (try teach Parse doing this) and hope that notContainedIn:arrayOfLikedObjectIds is going to benefit from a sorted array, or have a huge performance penalty. 

I don't know a good solution, but it seems like comparing two tables on a backend should be quite efficient since those are probably not array-backed.